# How to solve this logic using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

100 virtual user in thread count. out of 100 first 20 need to hit the URL  and after some time next 20  need to hit the URL.  So that I need to  5 different throughputs.

Comment: Ultimate threadgroup and throughput controller and delay of some time (as expected) can be used to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Concurrency thread groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) along with the [Throughput shaping timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/).

You can download these plugins by using [Plugins manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).

Answer (score 0):

Using Throughput controller u can achieve desired result.

[image: Throughput controller]

For more information

[ThroughputControler Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)